# Linux script that reads a input file

Tags: linux

I would like to seek for your help on how to write a simple bash script that reads an input file (e.g. txt file) that has a list into it (e.g. numbers/letters), process it and use that list to delete single/multiple lines on a different txt file. I tried using sed with no luck.

Hope someone can help me...

Thanks in advance and more power!

Comment: Post what you have so far

Comment: can you post any example data? otherwise the question is a little too broad

Comment: Hi Dinesh! Here's an example. txt file 1 has a list of let's say 1,2,4,5 and so on. Now I also have a txt file 2 which also has a list on it same as what txt 1 has. Now I want to use txt 1 as my source for the list and delete all the list that txt 2 has. Anything that txt 1 has, it will be deleted on the txt 2 file. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

To read a file, you can use the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="$1"

while read line
do
    #process each line
done < file
```